# Does log4j2 have the capability to log the root cause of an exception first?

Tags: java, log4j, logback

I have just found out that [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#rootException) is able to reverse the order of wrapped stacktraces: using `%rEx` in your format pattern, [it will start with the innermost exception first](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2011/09/logging-exceptions-root-cause-first.html), following by exceptions in which the root cause is wrapped.

This seems to be a nice feature, but I haven't found anything about [log4j2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) doing something like that.

Is there a (builtin) way to achieve this with log4j2?

Comment: I know this is old, but this question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29426691/927019).