# Enhanced Throwable Renderer in log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

Is there an equivalent of Enhanced Throwable Renderer class ( which was present in log4j1 ) in log4j2 ?  I am migrating a library to log4j2  and I don't see this feature supported in log4j2. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In log4j2, the [PatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) has many options like `%ex{option}`, `%rEx{option}` or `%xEx{option}` that I suspect have the same functionality or more than Enhanced Throwable Renderer.